# Не могу задать правильно параметры для multiple background в ::before

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Необходимо сделать задний фон лендинга из трех картинок, которые при увеличении масштаба не разъезжались, а масштабировались под контейнер. Решила использовать `::before`, в нем прописать

```
&::before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
background: url("../img/lending-bg-1.jpg") no-repeat left,
  url("../img/lending-bg-2.jpg") no-repeat center,
  url("../img/lending-bg-3.jpg") no-repeat right;
width: 100%;
height: 900px;
top: -85px;
z-index: -1;
```

}

Однако дальше не знаю как им задать размер, который они должны занимать по ширине (33%, 34%, 33%).

Пробовала писать по отдельности каждое свойство, начиная с `background-image`, однако в таком случае даже

```
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat,no-repeat;
```

работает некорректно, так как не применяет значение для первого `img`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
background-image: url("../img/lending-bg-1.jpg"), url("../img/lending-bg-2.jpg"), url("../img/lending-bg-3.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top, center top, right top;
background-size: 33% auto, 34% auto, 33% auto;
```

или

```css
background-image: 
  url("../img/lending-bg-1.jpg") no-repeat left top / 33% auto,
  url("../img/lending-bg-2.jpg") no-repeat center top / 34% auto,
  url("../img/lending-bg-3.jpg") no-repeat right top / 33% auto;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! В первом варианте почему-то no-repeat не применяется к первому элементу и в связи с этим все плывет и не применяется толком. А второй вариант подошел, я пробовала так же раньше, но без разделителя, поэтому, видимо не получалось.

Comment: @deadbeathd07, возможно вы что-то не правильно указали, если в подобные параметры передать только одно значение, то оно будет вешаться на все. [Демо](https://jsfiddle.net/CbIPoK2513/ahw2trge/) того, что первый вариант работает.

Answer (score 0):

Что именно не получается? Попробовал в вашем коде добавить размер 33%, 34%, 33%. Кажется, всё работает.

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid tomato;
  
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
  
  background:        url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/3/31/Winniethepooh.jpg") no-repeat left,
  url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/d/dd/Pigletdisney.jpg") no-repeat center,
  
  url("https://ru.wikifur.com/w/images/c/c6/Tigger.png") no-repeat right;
  
  background-size: 33%, 34%, 33%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет! В вашем случае все работает, масштабируется. Однако в моем случае не подошло: картинки не масштабируются а просто либо наезжают друг на друга при малом размере экрана, либо разъезжаются далеко друг от друга при большом размере экрана. Могу предположить, что это связано с тем, что в моем варианте это псевдоэлемент, а в вашем просто bg div-а. Однако это лишь мое предположение.